# python telebot не получается проверить подписку на канал

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Пишу телеграмм бота на python telebot, написал код который должен проверять подписку на канал у человека, бот является владельцем канала и у него есть все права, пользователи для проверки уже были подписаны на канал.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['subscribe_to_channel'])
def process_subscribe_to_channel(call):
    """функция обрабатывающая кнопку подписаться при выводе стартового сообщения"""
    user = bot.get_chat_member(channel_id, call.from_user.id)
    if user and user.status in ['creator', 'administrator', 'member']:
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=None)
        select_role(call.message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Вы не подписались!")
```

Почему-то выдает ошибку на user_id(A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: user not found). В качестве channel_id вставлял как айди с минусом получаемым из бота getIDs bot, так и в строковом формате юзер нейм канала(@channelname), ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, оказывается я перепутал один из своих аккаунтов с ботов из-за чего у бота не было прав и в общем его не было в канале :)